# how can I play sound for long time when PN(push-notification) remote notification arrive

Tags: ios, objective-c, push-notification

How can I repeat sound file when PN(push-notification) arrive in my device using Objective- c.

Comment: Do you need to play sound when app is open or close state?

Comment: I need to play sound when PN arrive to the device in both condition open and close.

Comment: 30 seconds is fine? If yes, in push update `sound` value. Say `sound : yourfile.mp3` & add this `yourfile.mp3` in project

Comment: I know PN allow only 30 sec file but I need to play sound for 1hour.

Answer (score 0):

You can find how to Custom Alert Sounds in this website: [Managing Your App’s Notification Support](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/SupportingNotificationsinYourApp.html) and the ringtone ***can not be Over 30s***

> Preparing Custom Alert Sounds
>
> For remote notifications in iOS, you can specify a custom sound that iOS plays when it presents a local or remote notification for an app. The sound files must be in the main bundle of the client app.
>
> Custom alert sounds are played by the iOS system-sound facility, so they must be in one of the following audio data formats:
>
> Linear PCM
>
> MA4 (IMA/ADPCM)
>
> µLaw
>
> aLaw
>
> You can package the audio data in an aiff, wav, or caf file. Then, in Xcode, add the sound file to your project as a nonlocalized resource of the app bundle.
>
> You may use the afconvert tool to convert sounds. For example, to convert the 16-bit linear PCM system sound Submarine.aiff to IMA4 audio in a CAF file, use the following command in the Terminal app:
>
> `afconvert /System/Library/Sounds/Submarine.aiff ~/Desktop/sub.caf -d ima4 -f caff -v`
>
> You can inspect a sound to determine its data format by opening it in QuickTime Player and choosing Show Movie Inspector from the Movie menu.
>
> Custom sounds must be under 30 seconds when played. If a custom sound is over that limit, the default system sound is played instead.

You can make this example dictionary send to APNs server with your custom alert sound name for the value of ***'sound'***:

```
// Create the payload body
$body['aps'] = array(
                    'alert' => 'TestNotification',
                    'sound' => 'YourCustomAlertSoundName.caf',
                    'badge' => 8
```

After making a good ringtone to your project's main bundle, the important step is to add the sound file you added (YourCustomAlertSoundName.caf) to Build Phases-> Copy Bundle Resources in the Project Settings, and the ringtone can not be Over 30s, otherwise the system will enable the default ringtone (default).

Comment: I know PN allow only 30 sec file but I need to play sound for 1hour.

Comment: It’s not allowed by Apple so I think you can make your application to a fake-background state actually it is active all the time. Then you can run the code to ringing for one hour.

Answer (score 0):

You just have to set custom file into **sound**  on push payload. Put the same audio file into your build resource and just fire notification from server, it will play audio.

```
{
   "aps" : 
   { 
       "alert" : "This is your alert text" 
       "sound" : "YOUR_COSTOM_FILE_NAME.mp4"
   },
}
```

When the application is in foreground mode, then you need to play same audio file when you get receive notification.

Comment: I know PN allow only 30 sec file but I need to play sound for 1hour.

Comment: You can play more than 30 seconds when your app is active. You can play any mp3 when your application is open.

Comment: I need to play in both case foreground and background.

Comment: You can do in foreground only, Apple is not allowed while your app is not running or its in background.

Comment: When PN came in to device in app inactive state ,which method got call ?

Comment: It won't any method when your app is in inactive state. Your app will get notify when user click on it.